# Animating bar graphs in CSS

Tags: css, animation

I want to achieve an animated bar graph similar to the one seen on the header of http://www.chartjs.org/

It is a visual animation of just a div, so its not pulling any raw data.

I've put together some CSS animation code, but this code increases the div's height from the bottom rather than the top. Could someone help sort this out so it animates like a normal graph, increasing upwards in height, not downwards in CSS2 / CSS3?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 


.div0 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

.div1 {  
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 2s infinite ; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: myfirst 2s infinite;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes 

myfirst {
    from, 15%  {background:red; height:120px}
    26%, 42%  {background:red; height:210px} 
    42%, 75%  {background:red; height:190px}
    75%, 100% {background:red; height:120px}
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "div0">
<div class = "div1"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to modifying the height property, you can adjust the `margin-top` property, or the `top` positioning property. Suppose for example that the max. height of your bar is `200px`, then for every frame your bar's `height` + `margin-top` should be = the max. height, like this:

```
myfirst {
    from, 15%  {background:red; margin-top: 20px; height: 180px;} /* = 200 */
    26%, 42%  {background:red; margin-top: 190px;height: 10px;}   /* = 200 */
    42%, 75%  {background:red; margin-top: 170px;height: 30px;}   /* = 200 */
    75%, 100% {background:red; margin-top: 20px;height: 180px;}   /* = 200 */
    }
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/xicab/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

Remove `position: relative;` from your `.div1` and add `bottom` to the class.

```
.div1 {  
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align: middle;

    /***** edits *****/
    /*position: relative;*/
    bottom: 200px;


    float: left;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 2s infinite ; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: myfirst 2s infinite;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Why are you using `position` twice anyways?

**Update :** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xRsrk/)

Comment: Good catches, however this only works with `position: fixed` or `absolute` meaning that if OP has multiple columns, he will have to set their offsets separately for each bar instead of just floating them.

Comment: Thank you @lkmhr. Position 2x times was a oversight. Just getting familiar with css anew.

Comment: hey @Tyblitz, was trying out the code again, here's what I've got so far. Is there a way to reduce so many lines of code to achieve the sam effect. I've added multiple graphs to create a more random effect. can this code be optimized or reduce the redundancies if any?    Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vdgY5/

Comment: Of course you can: give all the bars a shared class (or via a parent selector) & put all the shared properties in it. The only property that is different for every bar is the animation timing, so you can strip all the rest: like in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/vdgY5/2/)